# Java EE, JDBC and Tomcat

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jdbc, wamp

I'm trying to get data from a database using JSPs, but I get the following error when running it on server. Can anyone tell me what's wrong and show me how to fix it please?

```
type Rapport d''exception

message java.lang.NullPointerException

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
cause mère

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.vrf_jsp._jspService(vrf_jsp.java:84)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
note La trace complète de la cause mère de cette erreur est disponible dans les fichiers journaux de Apache Tomcat/7.0.47.
```

here's my code :

```
package utilitaire;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Database 
{

    public Connection con;

    public Connection createConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
            this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scoop_phase2p2","root","");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("driver introuvable");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.getErrorCode();
        }
        return this.con;
    }



}
```

/*******************************************************************/

```
<%@ page language = "java" %>
<%@ page import = "utilitaire.Admin" %>
<%@ page import = "utilitaire.Database" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.PreparedStatement" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.Connection" %>

<%
    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String mdp = request.getParameter("mdp");

    Database db = new Database();
    Connection conn = db.createConnection();
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM admin  WHERE login= ? AND DECODE(mdp, 'key')=?");
        query.setString(1, login);
        query.setString(2, mdp);
        ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery(); 
        for(int i=0; rs.next(); i++)
        if(i!=0)
            out.print("yup");
        else
            out.print("nope");
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.getCause();
    }

%>
```

Comment: NullPointerException happens when you try to use a method of not-valorized object.
When I have this problem, I insert some if( != null){}else{} in usage of every object for see the problem's source. At thefirst view, you don't create the connection  in JSP, beacause conn is null

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
```

Here driver should be Driver. Java class names are case-sensitive. For this reason your code throws the ClassNotFoundException:

```
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("driver introuvable");
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.getErrorCode();
    }
    return this.con;
```

There are several problems here. First of all, no matter what happens, you return "con". Even if it is still null. The the SQLException handler really does nothing. At least you should log the stacktrace.

```
   Database db = new Database();
Connection conn = db.createConnection();
try
{
    PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM admin  WHERE login= ? AND DECODE(mdp, 'key')=?");
```

What probably happens here: conn stays null, and you don't check it. Then you try to call prepareStatement on a null reference and get the NullPointerException.

Fix the "driver -> Driver" issue and instead of returning a null and swallowing the exception, rethrow it, so you get a chance to see what the problem is:

```
   try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scoop_phase2p2","root","");
        return this.con;
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
```

Comment: i've changed driver to Driver, but still i get the null pointer error, it's like my program can't find the mysql connector that i provided, i'm using mysql-connector-java5.1.18.bin.jar. i've included it like this: right click on my prject-- build path -- configure build path -- libraries -- add external jar. have i done something wrong??